# How to find out if 2 values in the same row exist in another table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to find out if 2 values in the same row exist in another table.
Only return the row if both values exist at the same time.
I can probably do 2 joins but is there an efficient way to do this?
Is there something like below?

```
table_1
+---------+---------------+------+
| id      | other_id      | key  |
+---------+---------------+------+
| 1       | 2             | A    |
| 2       | 1             | B    |
| 1       | 3             | C    |
| 4       | 2             | D    |
+---------+---------------+------+
table_2
+---------+
| id      |
+---------+
| 2       |
| 3       |
| 4       |
+---------+
SELECT
  *
from
  table_1
where
  (id, other_id)  in  (
    SELECT
      id
    from
      table_2
  )

output_table
+---------+---------------+------+
| id      | other_id      | key  |
+---------+---------------+------+
| 4       | 2             | D    |
+---------+---------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1                           
WHERE exists  (select 1 from table2 t2 where  t1.id=t2.id)                  
       and exists (select 1 from table2 t3 where  t1.anotherid=t3.id) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is similar to writing 2 joins which I am trying to avoid. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Cannot avoid 2 calls with AND condition for your case. Use exists when reference table is big. Join is good for small size refrence table

Answer (score 0):

Use [exists](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/corelated-subqueries-using-aliases.php):

```
SELECT
  *
from
  table_1 t1
where exists
(
    select id from table_2 t2
    where t1.id = t2.id or t1.other_id = t2.id;
)
```

Comment: Sorry not sure if I understand. For `t2`, I don't have a column `other_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think the `or` works in my case, I want to return true *only when both* `t1.id` and `t1.other_id` exist in `t2`, not just one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_1
where table_1.id in (select table_2.id from table_2)
```

try this , hope this help you!